# Group and get Average for Array Values Across Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to Mongo so if this is a basic question I apologize.

I have a several documents that have arrays with nested objects that I'm trying to query to get the average for a specific type.

Example of the document structure:

```
_id: ObjectID("ABC123")
StoreItems: Array
    0: Object
        Type: "Apple"
        Color: "Green"
        Size: "Small"
        Weight: "5"
    1: Object
        Type: "Orange"
        Color: "Orange"
        Size: "Small"
        Weight: "8"
    2: Object
        Type: "Grapes"
        Color: "Green"
        Size: "Small"
        Weight: "8"
```

I want to have a query that can group all Types that are Equal to Apples and get the Average Weight. I'm used to doing this with SQL but, that logic doesn't seem to apply here. This is what I got thus far and currently stuck:

```
$unwind: {
  path: "$StoreItems"
},
{
  $group: {
    "_id": "$StoreItems.Type",
    "count": {
      $avg: "$StoreItems.Weight"
    }
  }
```

Not sure how to include it to look for `Type = Apple` then get the average for the weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, If you wanted to filter collection with a criteria, you need to use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) :

```
[
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$StoreItems"
    }
  },
  { $match: { "StoreItems.Type": "Apple" } }, /** group will have docs only where type == Apple */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$StoreItems.Type",
      count: {
        $avg: "$StoreItems.Weight"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: That worked! One more question can you use the $match for across sections like {$match : {"db.Fruit.Warehouse.Type": "Boxed"} }, would that have to be a separate line

Comment: @texnoob : Is this :: `"db.Fruit.Warehouse.Type": "Boxed"` another field ? If yes then you can do in same `$match` then it would become an `AND` operation `"StoreItems.Type": "Apple" && "db.Fruit.Warehouse.Type": "Boxed"`